# Insert a file into the GAC using only the major version number

Tags: .net, versioning, gac

Inside the GAC, assemblies are keyed on their major version number only (sometimes major + minor), with zero build or revision numbers. However, the actual assemblies stored have full version numbers such as 3.4.6.1423.

How do you insert assemblies in such a way? Where does it get that the assembly with a build number like 3.4.6.1423 should be stored as 3.4.0.0 or 3.0.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assemblies are always stored in the GAC using their full version.
However, it is possible to use an [AssemblyInformationalVersion] or [AssemblyFileVersion] different to the [AssemblyVersion].

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.0.30319.239")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("4.0.30319.239")]
```